# python autopy problems/confusion

Tags: python, bitmap, autopy

so im trying to make a bot script that when a certain hex color is on a certain pixel it will execute some code to move the mouse,click etc. and i have it to where it takes a screenshot every 1 second to the same png file and updates the png file's pic. i have the hex color for the pixel cords print to the console so i can see if its updating or not. it never updates it just stays the same. ive tried writing this script many ways and sadly i only have one version to show you but hopefully you will understand what i was trying to accomplish. im on python 2.7 btw. thank you all for your time!!!!

```
import autopy
from time import sleep

color_grabber =    hex(autopy.bitmap.Bitmap.open("screen1.png").get_color(292,115))


def color_checker():
    global color_grabber
    color_grabber = color_grabber
    return

def mouse_move_click():
    autopy.mouse.smooth_move(433,320)
    autopy.mouse.click()

def screen_grab():
    autopy.bitmap.capture_screen().save("screen1.png")  

def the_ifs(mouse_move_click):
    if color_checker == "0xffcb05":
        mouse_move_click()

while 1==1:
    sleep(1)
    screen_grab()
    color_checker()
    the_ifs(mouse_move_click)
    print color_grabber
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is how you're using `color_grabber`. Saying `color_grabber = color_grabber` does nothing. What's happening in your code is that when you run it, after the imports, you define the value of `color_grabber` to be the color in your image. Then your while loop executes and in that loop you call `color_checker`. This function brings in the variable `color_grabber` from the global namespace and then you set that variable equal to itself. You're not re-executing the command you used to define `color_grabber` in the first place. You're just storing the color value back into itself so clearly its not going to change.

You also have a problem in how you're calling your mouse_move_click function. You don't want to pass in the function name, as that isn't really necessary. However, you also performed the check `color_checker == "0xffcb05"` which was comparing your function (the function itself, not the returned value) to the hex code. That doesn't do you any good. You want to compare the color. The solution is to pass the color into `the_ifs` and use that color to compare to the hex code. I should note though that you don't need to make `the_ifs` into its own function. Just put that if statement in your while loop. I left it how you had it though.

What you want is something like this.

```
import autopy
from time import sleep

def color_checker():
    color_grabber = hex(autopy.bitmap.Bitmap.open("screen1.png").get_color(292,115))
    return color_grabber

def mouse_move_click():
    autopy.mouse.smooth_move(433,320)
    autopy.mouse.click()

def screen_grab():
    autopy.bitmap.capture_screen().save("screen1.png")  

def the_ifs(color):
    if color == "0xffcb05":
        mouse_move_click()

while 1==1:
    sleep(1)
    screen_grab()
    color = color_checker()
    the_ifs(color)
    print color
```

Note that I have not run this code myself so I can't guarantee it works, but I believe it should.

Comment: thank you so much!!!!! im new to this site is there a way i can give you a rep or?

Comment: for some reason though the the_ifs/mouse_move_click functions arent activating and im sure that the right hex color code is being met....any ideas?

Comment: See my edit to your other problem. If my answer  helped, you can upvote it and/or choose it as the correct answer.

Comment: your edit? i dont see anything that changed. i cant upvote yet but i did select it as the answer!

Comment: im new to this site so im not for sure what your edit means. like you changed the code or?

Comment: Sorry, I posted my comment before I posted the edit. You should be able to reload and see the new paragraph I added describing how to fix your other problem and the code should be different now.

Comment: you sir are awesome!!! ty so much!!! everything is working fine now and i can finish this thanks to you!!!!

Comment: stuck again lol :/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36604153/autopy-mouse-click-not-working

Answer (score 1):

```
from autopy.mouse import LEFT_BUTTON
autopy.mouse.click(LEFT_BUTTON)
autopy.mouse.toggle(True, LEFT_BUTTON)
autopy.mouse.toggle(False, LEFT_BUTTON)
```

I see the need to do this in other people's code, but I don't understand why want to use the up and down after the click.In fact when I test on Windows 7, click is effective, but is not very correct, feel more like the down to my operation

Comment: 也许这些操作之间还需要一点点延迟（May also need a little delay）